# Find object in vector by comparing their member values

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I am working on a A* pathfinding algorithm in C++. I have the simple code below, now I need to find the object with lowest F. I know how to do this by iterating the vector and comparing it manualy, but I think there might be some other simplier way requering less code. Thanks for answers

```
struct Node
{
    int f;
};

void func()
{
    std::vector<Node> nodes;
    //fill nodes with some objects
    //now find Node object with smallest F
}
```

Comment: You are looking for `std::min_element`

Comment: To get decent performance, you need to use a priority queue data structure such as a heap. Iterating over a vector will be slow if you have a large number of nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[std::min_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) and lambda comparator seems to be most terse. By the way, using plain vector seems to defeat the purpose of using fast search algorithm such as A*. It's ok during developement, but for the final version you should use fast priority queue, such as heap-based [std::priority_queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you can use `std::priority_queue`, because it doesn't support changing the priority of elements. Boost.Heap can be used instead.

Comment: Could you point me to some explanation of difference between heap based container (havent met this yet) and constainers like vector or list?

Comment: @interjay - true, forgot A* needs that... I've always wished `std::priority_queue` did support this operation.

@user2715488 - well, the difference is complexity of minimal element retrieval. It's linear with vector, while it can be lower with more specialized data structure. As low as amortized constant with soft heap, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a temp int variable, and in this variable record the smallest value index of vector. Everytime when you push the new value to vector, you can compare it with the vector value with the temp index and record the new smallest value index.

Comment: That won't help, because when you remove the minimum element from the vector you'll have to iterate the whole vector to find the new minimum.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem when I was implementing A* algorithm.

Look at boost::multi_index. It allows you to have a map with many keys.
So you can have both: "sorting" Nodes by F (when one of the keys is F) and fast finding by Node's position (when second key is 'Node') what is required in A*.

For 'F' as a key you will need to specify that this key is nonunique as there can be many items with the same F value (so for this key multi_index needs to behave as std::multimap). Otherwise for such situation multimap will behave like a map and nodes with the same 'F' will not be stored.

When multi_index is used, you can take a first item by key 'F' and this will be and item with lowest 'F' value. (AFAIR you can specify the sorting order)

Comment: Thanks, after quick look into the Boost papers this looks like a lot better container than vector in this case, will study it more.